# Setting System.AssignedTo when System.AreaPath changed

Tags: xml, tfs, azure-devops

We are using Visual Studio Online, and we want to conditionally change the "Assigned to" when the "Area Path" changed. This will be hardcoded like:

```
WHEN value = "Area Path 1" THEN assigned To = "Roger Rabbit"
WHEN value = "Area Path 2" THEN assigned To = "Jessica Rabbit"
...
and so on.
```

But we tried to set the `WHEN` rule in the System.AssignedTo FIELD but an error is shown when we upload the file again to the server telling that we can't put a rule in this file.

How can we achieve this? Can we apply a rule in the Area Path (**WHENCHANGED**) and **COPY** conditionally a value TO the AssignedTo field?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, that rule is currently not supported in VSTS.

There is not a good way to do this. You have two options:

1. **Service Hook** - Use an IFTTT service, or create your own that can update the field. Try https://flow.microsoft.com or https://zapier.com/
2. **Extension** - You can create an extension for the work item form that runs JavaScript to update the fields that you want based on a trigger. https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/add-workitem-extension

If you cant do #1 easily then I think that #2 would be the best option. It needs some customisation especially if you are on the XML template rather than the Inheritance based templates.

Comment: Thanks for your comments!